# pandas dataframe how to merge all rows based on groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe with many columns, 2 are categorical and the rest are numeric:

```
df = [type1 , type2 , type3 , val1, val2, val3
       a       b        q       1    2     3
       a       c        w       3    5     2
       b       c        t       2    9     0
       a       b        p       4    6     7
       a       c        m       2    1     8]
```

I want to apply a merge based on the operation `groupby(["type1","type2"])` that will create the following dataframe:

```
df = [type1 , type2 ,type3, val1, val2, val3 , val1_a, val2_b, val3_b
       a       b       q      1    2     3      4        6      7
       a       c       w      3    5     2      2        1      8
       b       c       t      2    9     0      2        9      0
```

Please notice: there could be 1 or 2 rows at each groupby, but not more. in case of 1 - just duplicate the single row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter by `type1, type2`, then is created `MultiIndex`, reshaped by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), forward filling missing values per rows by `ffill`, converting to integers, sorting by counter level and last in list comprehension flatten `MultiIndex`:

```
g = df.groupby(["type1","type2"]).cumcount()

df1 = (df.set_index(["type1","type2", g])
        .unstack()
        .ffill(axis=1)
        .astype(int)
        .sort_index(level=1, axis=1))
df1.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' if b != 0 else a for a, b in df1.columns]
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
  type1 type2  val1  val2  val3  val1_1  val2_1  val3_1
0     a     b     1     2     3       4       6       7
1     a     c     3     5     2       2       1       8
2     b     c     2     9     0       2       9       0
```

Comment: @jezael Can you please explain? I didn't understand the solution

Comment: @okuoub - Can you bhe more specific, what is necessary explain more?

Comment: Why do you use ffill? Otherwise, thanks for the solution.

Comment: @BorutFlis - Because OP need fill non match values like last row not exist for `b,c` combination of types, so copied from previous values, I think `2,9,0`. You can see it if remove `.ffill(axis=1).astype(int)` for test difference

Comment: @jezrael Can you elaborate more on why using ffill?

Comment: @okuoub - Sure, because requrement is `in case of 1 - just duplicate the single row` - it means here is copy `2    9     0 ` to next columns, because not exist second row values for `b       c` combination.

Comment: @jezrael There is an additional categorical columns, "type3", that is always a string. I want the after the grouping - the value if "type3" for the new row will be taken from the first of the rows. Is this possible?

Comment: @okuoub - Not sure if understand, is possible post new question?

Comment: @okuoub - Can you add `df1 = df1.loc[:, ~df1.columns.str.contains('type3_\d+')]` after solution above?

Comment: @jezrael do you have a generic solution? In case there are multiple such columns?

Comment: @okuoub - hmmm, then use `df1 = df1.loc[:, ~df1.columns.str.contains('type3_\d+|type4_\d+|type5_\d+')]`